# manage Roles and Permissions in angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, permissions

I get a huge response of permissions around when I login into my application.
My question is what is the best way to assign those permissions to all of the pages in the application. permissions can be disabling/enabling the button , hiding/showing a div etc. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should create a service/factory that will handle this for you. The Angular way is to create a SPA (Single Page Application) so if you want it to handle permissions "to all of the pages" then you will either need to use cookies to store the permissions or for each page loaded, get the permissions again.

You can use [$cookieStore](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore).

Comment: Thank you. But how secure is it? anyone can access a cookie right? For my application security is a concern. Plz reply?

Comment: The permissions on the client side are **always** not secure. It should be just for user interface purposes. You should always be doing security checks on the server side.